# Qt/QML - How to customize Popup dimming effect?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, qtdeclarative

Hi is there a way to customize the dimming effect of the `Popup` when `modal === true`? I want the surrounding area of the `Popup` to be dimmed more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the dimming effect by overriding the `Overlay.modal` attached property. See the docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-overlay.html#modal-attached-prop)

```
Popup {
    id: popup
    width: 400
    height: 400
    modal: true
    visible: true

    Overlay.modal: Rectangle {
        color: "#aacfdbe7"  // Use whatever color/opacity you like
    }
}
```